# Compute 13*x by shifting and adding

Tags: assembly, mips, pcspim

I am just starting to learn assembly and having trouble getting this code to work so if anyone could help me out that would me much appreciated.

```
main:
ori $5,$0,x 
addu $10,$0,$5
sll $5,3,shft 
addu $10, $0, $5
sll $5,2,shft 
addu $10,$0 ,$5
```

"Write a program that computes 13*x. Do this by using register $5 for x and loading it at the beginning of the program with an ori instruction. Assume x is a positive integer represented in unsigned binary. Compute 13*x by shifting and adding. Don't use an explicit multiply instruction. Don't do input or output. Put the result in register $10 at the end of the program. Write the program so that the value for x can easily be changed."

Comment: Write a program that computes 13*x. Do this by using register $5 for x and loading it at the 
beginning of the program with an ori instruction. Assume x is a positive integer represented in 
unsigned binary. Compute 13*x by shifting and adding. 
Don't use an explicit multiply instruction. Don't do input or output. Put the result in register $10 
at the end of the program. Write the program so that the value for x can easily be changed.

Comment: What it comes down to is: 13x = 8x + 4x + x.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the basic steps. Since `13x` is the same as `(8 + 4 + 1)x`, you can do this by shifting and adding thus (pseudo-code):

```
move x to accumulator.

shift x left twice, it is now 4x.
add x to accumulator.

shift x left once more, it is now 8x.
add x to accumulator.
```

Now the accumulator holds `13x`. All you have to do is figure out the correct MIPS instructions to do that.

---

I'll tell you a couple of things you're doing wrong, though vaguely since this looks like homework :-)

Modifications to `$5` should be done in the order I've specified above. If you shift it three to the left, then another two to the left,  that's multiplying it by 2<sup>5</sup>, or `32`.

In addition, you may want to check the order of some of those arguments. They don't seem to gel with what is expected.